# How to get specific ul element li's text and href having no any class or id using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a html scrapped from a mailing list page like this:

```
<ul>
<li> <b>Messages sorted by:</b>
<a href="thread.html#start">[ thread ]</a>
<a href="author.html#start">[ author ]</a>
<a href="date.html#start">[ date ]</a>
<li><b><a href="https://mail.kde.org/mailman/listinfo/okular-devel">More info on this list...
                    </a></b></li>
</li></ul>, 


<ul>
<li><a href="000006.html">[Okular-devel] "why okular is cool and what's our focus" text
</a><a name="6"> </a>
<i>Albert Astals Cid
</i>
<li><a href="000000.html">[Okular-devel] playground/graphics/okular
</a><a name="0"> </a>
<i>Tobias Koenig
</i>
<li><a href="000001.html">[Okular-devel] playground/graphics/okular
</a><a name="1"> </a>
<i>Tobias Koenig
</i>
<li><a href="000004.html">[Okular-devel] Rotation &amp; object rects
</a><a name="4"> </a>
<i>Pino Toscano
</i>
<li><a href="000005.html">[Okular-devel] Rotation &amp; object rects
</a><a name="5"> </a>
<i>Albert Astals Cid
</i>
<li><a href="000002.html">[Okular-devel] Slow painting on QImage
</a><a name="2"> </a>
<i>Tobias Koenig
</i>
<li><a href="000003.html">[Okular-devel] Slow painting on QImage
</a><a name="3"> </a>
<i>Albert Astals Cid
</i>
</li></li></li></li></li></li></li></ul>, 


<ul>
<li> <b>Messages sorted by:</b>
<a href="thread.html#start">[ thread ]</a>
<a href="author.html#start">[ author ]</a>
<a href="date.html#start">[ date ]</a>
<li><b><a href="https://mail.kde.org/mailman/listinfo/okular-devel">More info on this list...
                    </a></b></li>
</li></ul>
```

You can see there are three `<ul>` elements having li elements in them and I only want to get the li elements of second `<ul>` element only that have `<LI>` in uppercase and the output should be like:

```
[Okular-devel] "why okular is cool and what's our focus" text - 000006.html
[Okular-devel] playground/graphics/okular - 000000.html
[Okular-devel] playground/graphics/okular - 000001.html
[Okular-devel] Rotation & object rects - 000004.html
and so on...
```

The format is the text of the `<LI>` element and the associated `<href>` link. My code is giving the li of all `<ul>` elements and the output is reapeating 2-3 times and I'm unable to extract out the href along with them -
My code:

```
for ele in soup.find_all('ul'):
    for litag in ele.find_all('li'):
        for link in litag.find_all('href'):
            print(litag.text + '-' + link)
```

It is not giving me the desired output. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing from the html you provided.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")

for el in soup.find_all('ul'):
    for i in el.find_all("li"):
        if i.find("li"):
            print(i.li.a.text.strip(), "---", i.li.a['href'].strip())
```

**Output:**

```
More info on this list... --- https://mail.kde.org/mailman/listinfo/okular-devel
[Okular-devel] playground/graphics/okular --- 000000.html
[Okular-devel] playground/graphics/okular --- 000001.html
[Okular-devel] Rotation & object rects --- 000004.html
[Okular-devel] Rotation & object rects --- 000005.html
[Okular-devel] Slow painting on QImage --- 000002.html
[Okular-devel] Slow painting on QImage --- 000003.html
More info on this list... --- https://mail.kde.org/mailman/listinfo/okular-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a find on the anchor tags:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
ele = soup.find_all('ul')[1]     # use only the 2nd one

for litag in ele.find_all('li'):
    for link in litag.find_all('a', href=True):
        print('{} - {}'.format(link.get_text(strip=True), link['href']))
```

Giving you:

```
[Okular-devel] "why okular is cool and what's our focus" text - 000006.html
[Okular-devel] playground/graphics/okular - 000000.html
[Okular-devel] playground/graphics/okular - 000001.html
[Okular-devel] Rotation & object rects - 000004.html
[Okular-devel] Rotation & object rects - 000005.html
[Okular-devel] Slow painting on QImage - 000002.html
[Okular-devel] Slow painting on QImage - 000003.html
[Okular-devel] playground/graphics/okular - 000000.html
[Okular-devel] playground/graphics/okular - 000001.html
[Okular-devel] Rotation & object rects - 000004.html
[Okular-devel] Rotation & object rects - 000005.html
[Okular-devel] Slow painting on QImage - 000002.html
[Okular-devel] Slow painting on QImage - 000003.html
[Okular-devel] playground/graphics/okular - 000001.html
[Okular-devel] Rotation & object rects - 000004.html
[Okular-devel] Rotation & object rects - 000005.html
[Okular-devel] Slow painting on QImage - 000002.html
[Okular-devel] Slow painting on QImage - 000003.html
[Okular-devel] Rotation & object rects - 000004.html
[Okular-devel] Rotation & object rects - 000005.html
[Okular-devel] Slow painting on QImage - 000002.html
[Okular-devel] Slow painting on QImage - 000003.html
[Okular-devel] Rotation & object rects - 000005.html
[Okular-devel] Slow painting on QImage - 000002.html
[Okular-devel] Slow painting on QImage - 000003.html
[Okular-devel] Slow painting on QImage - 000002.html
[Okular-devel] Slow painting on QImage - 000003.html
[Okular-devel] Slow painting on QImage - 000003.html
```

Adding `href=True` ensures only tags which contain an `href` are returned.